# Api Error: TSocket read 0 bytes when using hue with hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hue

Here is my settings in hue config

[hbase]

# Comma-separated list of HBase Thrift servers for

# clusters in the format of '(name|host:port)'.

hbase_clusters=(Cluster|MasterIP:ThriftPort)

# Hard limit of rows or columns per row fetched before truncating.

## truncate_limit = 500

but when I connect to hue webpage and switch to Hbase tab, it shows
[image]

Log:
[08/Dec/2013 19:30:13 +0000] middleware   INFO     Processing exception: Api Error: TSocket read 0 bytes: Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/ubuntu/workspaces/hue/hue-master/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response

```
response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
```

File "/home/ubuntu/workspaces/hue/hue-master/apps/hbase/src/hbase/views.py", line 69, in api_router

```
return api_dump(HbaseApi().query(*url_params))
```

File "/home/ubuntu/workspaces/hue/hue-master/apps/hbase/src/hbase/api.py", line 47, in query

```
raise PopupException(_("Api Error: %s") % e.message)
```

PopupException: Api Error: TSocket read 0 bytes

[08/Dec/2013 19:30:13 +0000] thrift_util  INFO     Thrift saw a transport exception: TSocket read 0 bytes

[08/Dec/2013 19:30:13 +0000] thrift_util  WARNING  Out of retries for thrift call: getTableNames

[08/Dec/2013 19:30:13 +0000] thrift_util  DEBUG    Thrift call: hbased.Hbase.Client.getTableNames(args=(), kwargs={})

[08/Dec/2013 19:30:13 +0000] thrift_util  INFO     Thrift exception; retrying: TSocket read 0 bytes

[08/Dec/2013 19:30:13 +0000] thrift_util  DEBUG    Thrift call: hbased.Hbase.Client.getTableNames(args=(), kwargs={})

[08/Dec/2013 19:30:13 +0000] thrift_util  INFO     Thrift exception; retrying: TSocket read 0 bytes

[08/Dec/2013 19:30:13 +0000] thrift_util  DEBUG    Thrift call: hbased.Hbase.Client.getTableNames(args=(), kwargs={})

[08/Dec/2013 19:30:13 +0000] access       INFO     118.163.58.205 tracy - "POST /hbase/api/getTableList/Cluster HTTP/1.1"

Answer (score 0):

Is HBase Master and the Thrift server still up? (do you have the logs?)

Also are you using security and which HBase version are you using?

Comment: Yes, Master and Thrift server are up. Hbase Version is :hbase-0.96.0

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the localtimes on the instances. 
I have had the same issue and I have it fixed now after having the same timezones on all instances and the HUE timezone

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your hbase "core-site.conf":

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.thrift.support.proxyuser</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.regionserver.thrift.http</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
```